# How do I correctly add additional options to a WooCommerce payment gateway's options page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm developing a plugin that will perform some functions when a particular payment gateway is present in WooCommerce, and it makes sense for my plugin options to be added to the same options page as the gateway's options. I don't want to change the behaviour of the gateway in any way, just display the options for my plugin on the same options page.

Based on [this document](https://woocommerce.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/), I came up with this code.

```php
<?php

class MyPluginClass {   
    
    /**
    * Initialise the class
    **/

    public function init() {

        // Hook into the Payment tab of WooCommerce settings and add 
        // options to the Gateway's options page
        // (Tab's ID is 'checkout' even though the tab is called payments)

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_checkout', array($this, 'add_options_to_gateway_options_page'), 10, 2 );
    }

    /**
    * Add options to the gateway's options page
    **/

    public function add_options_to_gateway_options_page( $settings, $current_section_id ) {

        // If the current section is not the required gateway, return the settings
        // (replace gateway_id with the actual gateway ID. this is 
        // the 'section' argument from the URL when viewing the gateway's options page)

        if ( 'gateway_id' != $current_section_id  ) return $settings;

        // Create settings

        $my_settings = array(
            array (
                'title' => __('Automation options'),
                'type' => 'title',
                'description' => ''
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 'my_plugin_enabled',
                'name' => 'my_plugin_enabled',
                'title' => __('Gateway automations', 'my_plugin'),
                'label' => __('Enable gateway automations', 'my_plugin'),
                'description' => __('Enable the gateway automations plugin', 'my_plugin'),
                'desc_tip' => true,
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'default' => 'yes'
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'sectionend',
                'id' => 'my_plugin'
            )
        );

        return $my_settings;
    }
}

$myPlugin = new MyPluginClass;
$myPlugin->init();
```

The checkbox works and its value is saving to the DB and reading just fine on page load, along with the rest of the options on the page. The title and checkbox are displayed on the screen in the expected location and the checkbox is checked on the first load as per the default. But, the label and tooltip with the description are not displayed.

```html
// The resulting HTML

<h2>Automation options</h2>
<table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top" class="">
            <th scope="row" class="titledesc">Gateway automations</th>
            <td class="forminp forminp-checkbox">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Gateway automations</span></legend>
                    <label for="my_plugin_enabled">
                        <input name="my_plugin_enabled" id="my_plugin_enabled" type="checkbox" class="" value="1">
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Screenshot showing result]

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug somewhere?

UPDATE

So I was doing something slightly wrong. I changed `'description' => __('...` to `'desc' => __('...` and now the description is showing just below the checkbox, but not in a help bubble. Strangely, I've added a few more fields below the checkbox following the same scheme and the description help bubble IS working.

However, `'label' => __('...` is still not working for any of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the right hook,I believe that will fire on customer checkout as well.

here is a quick function to do what you are after, but it seems like you can only have either a 'label' or a tooltip, with the desc_tip being the thing that sets it to the tooltip.

if you're making your own gateway it's far better to extend an existing class and use `$this->init_form_fields();` but if you know the id's of the gateways you are targeting this should do what you are looking for

```php
/**
 * Init action to add the custom field to the payment gateways we want.
 * @return void
 */
function add_custom_field_to_gateways(): void {
    $gateway_ids_to_add_options_to = array(
        'cod',
        'bacs',
    );
    foreach ( $gateway_ids_to_add_options_to as $gateway_id ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_' . $gateway_id, 'add_my_plugin_options', 10, 1 );
    }
} add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_field_to_gateways' );

/**
 * Add custom fields to the payment gateway settings page
 * by hooking into the gateway's settings array.
 *
 * @param array $settings
 * @return array
 */
function add_my_plugin_options( array $settings ): array {
    $settings['my_plugin_enabled'] = array(
        'id'          => 'my_plugin_enabled',
        'name'        => 'my_plugin_enabled',
        'title'       => __( 'Gateway automations', 'my_plugin' ),
        'label'       => __( 'Enable gateway automations', 'my_plugin' ),
        'description' => __( 'Enable the gateway automations plugin', 'my_plugin' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'type'        => 'checkbox',
        'default'     => 'yes',
    );
    $settings['settingWithLabel']  = array(
        'title'       => 'Setting with label',
        'label'       => 'Setting with label',
        'type'        => 'text',
        'description' => 'Setting with label',
        'desc'        => 'Setting with label',
        'default'     => 'default',
        'desc_tip'    => false,
    );
    return $settings;
}
```